# Mysql Error executing simple code

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a SQL request with a function that already works and look like this :

```
SELECT fnStripTags('this <html>is <b>a test</b>, nothing more</html>');
```

When I execute this SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_lang` (`description`) VALUES (
    SELECT fnStripTags(description) FROM ps_product_lang 
    WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang = id_lang AND ps_product_lang.id_product = id_product 
) WHERE description IS NOT NULL
```

I got this error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'SELECT fnStripTags(ps_product_lang.description) FROM
ps_product_lang WHERE ps_pr' at line 1
```

Comment: and what is id_lang and id_product?

Answer (score 0):

The `insert-select` statement doesn't have a `values` keyword in it:

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_lang (description) 
SELECT      fnStripTags(description) 
FROM        ps_product_lang 
WHERE       ps_product_lang.id_lang = id_lang AND 
            ps_product_lang.id_product = id_product AND
            description IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..No need `values` for insert staement

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_lang (description)
  SELECT fnStripTags(description)
   FROM ps_product_lang
   WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang = id_lang
     AND ps_product_lang.id_product = id_product
       And description IS NOT NULL
```